# Animation of the content with a new slide

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help with animation. I have 4 slides that move on their own after a time interval. When I load(reload) the webpage the animation is done exactly as I need it. But nothing happens after the move, why? I tried deleting the classname "slideTextFromBottom" before scrolling, but unfortunately it didn't help. Thank you for the advice.

```js
function initGallery() {
    slideIndex = 0;
    slides = document.querySelectorAll(".imageHolder");
    slides[slideIndex].style.opacity = 1;
    captionText = document.querySelector(".captionText");
    captionText.innerHTML = slides[slideIndex].querySelector(".captionText").innerHTML;

    dots = [];
    var dotsContainer = document.getElementById("dotsContainer"), i;
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        let dot = document.createElement("span");
        dot.classList.add("dots");
        dot.setAttribute("onclick", "moveSlide(" + i + ")");
        dotsContainer.append(dot);
        dots.push(dot);
    }
    dots[slideIndex].classList.add("active");
}

window.onload = function () {
    initGallery();
    var timer = null;

    function setTimer() {
        timer = setInterval(function () {
            plusSlides(1);
        }, 10000);
    }
    setTimer();
}
function plusSlides(n) {
    moveSlide(slideIndex + n);
}
function moveSlide(n) {

    var i, current, next;
    var moveSlideAnimClass = {
        forCurrent: "",
        forNext: ""
    }

    var slideTextAnimClass;
    if (n > slideIndex) {
        if (n >= slides.length) { n = 0; }
        moveSlideAnimClass.forCurrent = "moveLeftCurrentSlide";
        moveSlideAnimClass.forNext = "moveLeftNextSlide";
        slideTextAnimClass = "slideTextFromBottom";
    } else if (n < slideIndex) {
        if (n < 0) { n = slides.length - 1 }
        moveSlideAnimClass.forCurrent = "moveRightCurrentSlide";
        moveSlideAnimClass.forNext = "moveRightNextSlide";
        slideTextAnimClass = "slideTextFromBottom";
    }
    if (n != slideIndex) {
        next = slides[n];
        current = slides[slideIndex];

        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].className = "imageHolder";
            slides[i].style.opacity = 0;
            dots[i].classList.remove("active");
        }
        current.classList.add(moveSlideAnimClass.forCurrent);
        next.classList.add(moveSlideAnimClass.forNext);
        dots[n].classList.add("active");
        slideIndex = n;
        captionText.style.display = "none";
        captionText.innerHTML = slides[n].querySelector(".captionText").innerHTML;
        captionText.className = "captionText " + slideTextAnimClass;
        captionText.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

```css
.uvodni {
    width: 100%;
    height: 65vh;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.imageHolder {
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -2;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 65vh;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.imageHolder .captionText {
    display: none;
}
.captionTextHolder {
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.captionUnderHolder {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.captionText {
    border-radius: 1px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 70%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 30%;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.leftArrow,
.rightArrow {
    width: 40px;
    background-color: #0003;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 5;
    transition: background 1s;
    height: 40px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #FFF9;
}
.rightArrow {
    left: auto;
    right: 10px;
}
.leftArrow:hover,
.rightArrow:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    background-color: #E0261C;
}
.arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 3px solid #FFF9;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-left: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.leftArrow:hover .arrow {
    border: 3px solid #FFF;
    border-left: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}
.rightArrow:hover .arrow {
    border: 3px solid #FFF;
    border-left: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}
.arrow.arrowLeft {
    transform: rotateZ(-135deg);
}
.arrow.arrowRight {
    transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}
#dotsContainer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 95%;
    z-index: 5;
}
#dotsContainer .dots {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 5px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.5s;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
#dotsContainer .dots:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
#dotsContainer .dots:hover,
#dotsContainer .dots.active {
    background-color: #E0261C;
}
.moveLeftCurrentSlide {
    animation-name: moveLeftCurrent;
    animation-duration: 0.8s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.moveLeftNextSlide {
    animation-name: moveLeftNext;
    animation-duration: 0.8s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes moveLeftCurrent {
    from {
        margin-left: 0;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        margin-left: -100%;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes moveLeftNext {
    from {
        margin-left: 100%;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        margin-left: 0;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
.moveRightCurrentSlide {
    animation-name: moveRightCurrent;
    animation-duration: 0.8s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes moveRightCurrent {
    from {
        margin-left: 0;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        margin-left: 100%;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
.moveRightNextSlide {
    animation-name: moveRightNext;
    animation-duration: 0.8s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes moveRightNext {
    from {
        margin-left: -100%;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        margin-left: 0;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
.slideTextFromBottom {
    animation-name: slideTextFromBottom;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;

}
.captionText h6 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #E0261C;
    /*padding: 1em 0 1em 0;*/
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-top: 2.5em;
    margin-bottom: .6em;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
}
.captionText h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #E0261C;
    /*margin-bottom: 1em;*/
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 2em;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
}
.captionText p {
    color: #000;
    padding: .6em 0 1em 0;
    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
@keyframes slideTextFromBottom {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        margin-top: 180px;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
}
```

```html
            <div class="uvodni">
                <div class="leftArrow" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">
                    <span class="arrow arrowLeft"></span>
                </div>        
                <div class="rightArrow" onclick="plusSlides(1)">
                    <span class="arrow arrowRight"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="captionTextHolder">
                    <div class="captionUnderHolder">
                        <div id="popisek" class="captionText slideTextFromBottom">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>        
                <div class="imageHolder" style="background-image: url(https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/109666.jpg);">
                    <div class="captionText">
                        <h6>H6 Text - 1</h6>
                        <h3>H3 Text</h3>
                        <p style="text-transform: none;">Something </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="imageHolder" style="background-image: url(https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/109666.jpg);">
                    <div class="captionText">
                        <h6>H6 Text - 2</h6>
                        <h3>H3 Text</h3>
                        <p>Something</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="imageHolder" style="background-image: url(https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/109666.jpg);">
                    <div class="captionText">
                        <h6>H6 Text - 3</h6>
                        <h3>H3 Text</h3>
                        <p>Something</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="imageHolder" style="background-image: url(https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/109666.jpg);">
                    <div class="captionText">
                        <h6>H6 Text - 4</h6>
                        <h3>H3 Text</h3>
                        <p>Something</p>
                    </div>
                </div>        
                <div id="dotsContainer"></div>        
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **slick slider** for good and less headache with high online support community.

https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

```
$('.autoplay').slick({
  
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
});
```

Comment: I want to learn something, not just copy the code. But thank your for answer.